# Why is fwrite writing each character so many times?

Tags: c, file, io

I'm trying to write a program that uncompresses a file which was already compressed using run length encoding. For some reason each character is getting printed to the file many times. For example if the input file contains `1l1i1n...` my output file is showing `llllllllll...`

I've tried printing the reps variable from the for loop to the terminal to make sure it is set to the correct number of repetitions, and even tried using fprintf but getting the same results. Im not sure what it is but there must be something here Im not understanding?

By the way, the compressed file is opened in binary mode as well from the main function.

```
  int uncompress_file(FILE *fd_compressed, const char *fname_out)
  {
          FILE *fd_out;
          if (fd_compressed == NULL) {
                  fprintf(stderr, ...);
                  return -1;
          }
          if ((fd_out = fopen(fname_out, "wb")) == NULL) {
                  fprintf(stderr, ...);
                  return -1;
          }
          unsigned char cur, reps;
          int i = 0;

          while (fread(&cur, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fd_compressed) > 0) {
                  if (i % 2 == 0) {
                          reps = cur;
                  }
                  else {
                          for (int j = 0; j < reps; j++)
                                  fwrite(&cur, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, fd_out);
                  }
                  i++;
          }
          fclose(fd_out);
          return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Does the input file literally contain `"1l1i1n"`? As in, the character `'1'` (i.e. the byte 0x31)? Because `'1'` is not the same as `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your line `reps = cur`. If your file is `1l1i1n` then when we first enter the loop, reps will be assigned the value `1`. But this is ASCII `1`, not the actual number 1. A 1 in ASCII maps to the decimal 49, so you will get 49 `l`'s. To convert the char from an ASCII number to the proper `int` value, you can subtract 48 from it, i.e. `reps = cur - 48`.

Note that this, along with your code, only works if the maximum number possible is 9 (no double-digits)

Comment: Ah, still new to C so that went right over my head while writing it. This solves that though. Thanks

Comment: Would using a delimiter between the count and actual character be the best way to make this work for more than 9 consecutive characters? Of course I would edit the function that compresses also.

Comment: That's an option. Alternatively, a simple improvement that increases the limit to 255 is instead of using ASCII for the number, you just use a raw byte, so 1 would be a null byte (0x00), 2 would be 0x01, 3 would be 0x02, etc. That way you can keep the simplicity of just alternating every byte. Although it does have the downside that your compressed file won't be easily readable in text editors anymore.